# Check if dollar sign exists in the variable

Tags: perl

```
$var = 'C1_0327_GA2_OAX$DW';
```

I need to validate if the dollar (`$`) sign exists in the variable or not using Perl?

Could you please let me know how to check this?

Answer (score 3):

A fast way to count the number of occurencies of a single character is with [transliteration operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr)

```
if ($var =~ tr/$//) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a [regular expression](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

for my $var (qw(C1_0327_GA2_OAX$DW C1_0327_GA2_OAXDW)) {
    if ($var =~ /\$/) {
        print "$var has dollar\n";
    }
    else {
        print "$var has no dollar\n";
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
C1_0327_GA2_OAX$DW has dollar
C1_0327_GA2_OAXDW has no dollar
```

Since `$` has special meaning in a regular expression, it must be escaped; I used a backslash to escape it.

Answer (score 2):

There's also [index](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index), which is handy when you are looking for a fixed string. It returns -1 when it doesn't find that substring:

```
if( -1 != index $string, $substring ) { ... }
```

In this case:

```
if( -1 != index $var, '$' ) { ... }
```